# Python: weird import behaviour

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, relative-import

I have a package with the following structure

```
projectX
├── data 
├── results
└── projectX
    ├── stats
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── stats_worker.py
    │   └── stats_wroker2.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main_worker.py
    └── interface.py
```

Notice that the project folder and the source folder share the same name (projectX).

The problem is a bit complex and needs some premises to be done

#### Premises:

I always launch the interface and always have launched the interface. No other script is called

My problem first arose when trying to import main_worker from stats_worker2.

I couldn't make it work as a relative import. So I tried to
append the parent directory to the sys.path, both from stats_worker2 and from the interface (separately). I tried various ways that I don't remember.

It finally worked by adding the following lines to stats_worker2

```
sys.path.append('../projectX')
from projectX import main_worker
```

#### Now the weirdness starts

*After calling the script a couple of times (I don't remember exactly how many), the above sintax doesn't work anymore. Because there is an:
    ImportError: No module named projectX*

**EDIT**: the above part in italic was due to the fact that I was missing an `__init__.py` in the projectX source folder. All other symptoms are still there.

But, weird enough, I can now import successfully the main worker from the stats_worker2 with:

```
import main_worker
```

**Without any** directory being appended to sys.path!

However, **Sphinx doesn't work anymore!** Specifically, it fails to import all of the modules of the projectX package.

Bonus weirdness

I used to successfully import stats_worker from the interface, now I still can import it, but my IDE (Pycharm) marks that import as unused. It is actually used and if I comment the import, the interface crashes as it is expected to (I already have invalidated Pycharm cache)

Comment: Are you missing an `__init__.py` in projectX?

Comment: yeah sorry, I deleted it at some point for a test and forgot to add back. I'll edit the question accordingly now that I have restored it (spoiler: its practically the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an empty `__init__.py` file into the *source root*<sup>†</sup>.
2. Your runtime environment will need to be setup so that the *project root*<sup>††</sup> is visible in `sys.path`.  The project root should *not* have an `__init__.py`.  It isn't necessary for the project directory name to match the package name, but that doesn't really harm anything either.
3. Remove any `sys.path.append` stuff from python source files, and don't ever do that again.
4. `from projectX import main_worker` is a correct import statement for the `stats_worker2.py` module.  Don't use `import main_worker`.

For step 2, the usual way to do this is via "installing" your package, with `python setup.py develop`.  i.e. you need to write a `setup.py`.  Since you apparently don't have a `setup.py`, as a cheap workaround you can `export PYTHONPATH=<absolute_path_to_project_root>` instead.

<sup>†</sup><sub>Source root is the deeper `projectX` dir, it's the same directory which contains the `main_worker.py` module.</sub>

<sup>††</sup><sub>Project root is the shallow `projectX` dir, it's the same directory which contains `data` and `results` subdirectories.</sub>

Comment: I added the`__init__.py` file to the source projectX. Now the import works correcly. However, after trying to `export PYTHONPATH=<absolute_path_to_project_root>` the problem persists. Sphinx cannot find any module of the `projectX` package and my IDE still marks `stats_worker` as an unused import.

Comment: You will need to export the environment variable in your IDE too.  It won't pick up the ones from a bash session, since it doesn't use that environment.