# Python Import modules 1 level above. Without using Sys.path

Tags: python

Update: I have changed my file directory

I have a directory structure as follows and I would like to import a module in a parent directory.

```
**project**/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    **APP_NAME**/
        **parser**/
            __init__.py
            parser.py
    **test**/
        __init__.py
        parser_test.py
```

parser.py

```
class Parser(object):
  pass
```

main.py (Works fine)

```
from APP_NAME.parser.parser import Parser
```

parser_test.py (Throws error)

```
from ..APP_NAME.parser.parser import Parser
```

Throws the following error at parser_test.py

```
Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I know I can fix it using sys.path.append(), but I want to import it like a package the way I did it in main.py.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42010819/674039

Comment: TL;DR either write a `setup.py` or use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  `main.py` will also only work from the same directory!  details in the linked answer above.

Comment: @wim what do you mean main.py will only work from the same directory?

Comment: Try and cd to `/tmp` and then run `python /path/to/project/main.py`.

Comment: Yes that works. What about it? I don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

I had to check back at one of my projects for a reference.

To test files in the `tests` folder you must first create `setup.py`, so that you can install you project for python to use it.

If on linux use the command, `sudo python setup.py install` to install the package. When changes have been made to the project, you must install again for the changes to take place.

These folder will be created in your root project directory after installing.
`build`, `dist`, and `project.egg-info`.

You may need to clean the build directory before re-installing to update.

`python setup.py clean`
`python setup.py build`
`python setup.py install`

### Project Structure

```
project
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   └── parser_test.py
│    
└── project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── main.py
    └── parser
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── parser.py
        └── parser.pyc
```

#### project/`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup


# Make sure the project name will not conflict with other libraries
# For example do not name the project, 'os', 'sys', ect.

setup(
    name='project', 
    description='My project description',
    author='your_online_name',
    license='MIT', # Check out software licenses
    packages=['project', 'tests']
)
```

#### project/tests/`parser_test.py`

```
from project.parser import Parser

parser = Parser()
```

#### project/project/`__init__.py`

```
from . import parser
```

#### project/project/parser/`__init__.py`

```
from .parser import Parser
```

#### project/project/parser/`parser.py`

```
class Parser(object):
    pass
```

Comment: So there is pretty much no way to have the test file beneath my code? It looks like ur solution requires the test to be on top of beside the code.

Comment: And what if I have multiple test files? It would make my folder very messy.

Comment: Yes it would, unfortunately the only way I know how to use multiple test files is to create the tests folder in the outer layer and make sure the latest version of your project is installed. To do this you need to use `setuptools` and a `setup.py`. Then install the package each time you want to test your code. Give me a few minutes, i'll update the answer.

Comment: Check out https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html for a `setuptools` example.

Comment: I cant do setup.py because I am not an administrator, and I can't install things into my python's installation folder. 

Is there any other way to accomplish this without using setup.py?

Comment: ALso, my Main.py can call the modules just fine. So I dont understand Why my test.py cannot call it?

Comment: Well if `test.py` is in the `test` folder and `project` is not installed, Then `test.py` has no clue as to what `project` is since it's not in the same directory. You either need `test.py` where your `main.py` is or you need to install your package so any `.py` file throughout your system can import `project`

Comment: I thought something like `from ..APP.package.module import some_class` will do the trick.

Comment: You cant call a python file that uses  relative imports. releative imports are `.project` or `..project` notice how your `main.py` file just imports `project.parser.Parser` not `.project.parser.Parser`. The latter is a releative import and python will thow an exception at you when running the file directly. The former however will run just fine.

Comment: Even if I put the test file right next to the modules, it still doesnt work... I really dont want to resort to sys.path.append()...

Comment: I updated the answer to support `setuptools` which you should use. It's a library for installing packages and uploading them to pypi for public access or cloud storage if its a personal project(mine are never important enough to gain public attention).

Comment: Then the test files in the `tests` folder will work.

Comment: If you look at the answer below, @adrien el zein shows a solution using `import ..` even thought it didn't work for me.

Comment: pythons importing is wacked out and has always been in issue. You could use `virtualenv` to create a virtual python environment which wouldn't need administration permissions to install packages. But to install virtualenv you would admin permission. Setting a virtualenv up is extremely simple, but agian you NEED to install virtualenv before you can use. http://www.simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/

Comment: Theres really no other way, when developing, its assumed you have permissions to install packages, otherwise you can't really develop.

Comment: If you can't get permissions then just have a messy root directory with all your test files alongside your `main.py` just add a prefix `test_` to every test file for readability . `test_parser.py`

Comment: I thought of a way this might work. create two files next to `main.py` One of these scripts lets call it `test_imports.py` will import the test files to run them. The second script `test.py` will import `test_imports.py` running test_imports and test_imports will then run your test files. The key is to run execute a script that has no relative imports. `test_imports.py` will have releative import as you will be accessing the `tests` directory.

Comment: Never mind I tried it and it doesn't work. It seems your only option is to contact you admin and explain your situation.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be using absolute import within your package. In-package imports should be done with relative imports this way:

parser_test.py

```
from ..parser.parser import Parser
```

With relative imports in Python, the first point refers to the file's directory and each extra point refers to the parent directory.

In this case, you would be pointing to the `project/parser/parser.py` file which from `test_parser.py` standpoint's is `../parser.py`

If you are using Python 2, you should add the following line at the top of all the files in your `parser` package

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

This will avoid that you use absolute imports inside you package files by mistake.

Still assuming you are working with Python 2, you should also import `unicode_literals` for native unicode support and `print_function` to replace the `print` command by the `print()` function.

However, I would rather have my tests in the top folder of the **package**, which, assuming the package is called **project** and not parser, would give the following directory structure:

```
project/ # top project directory
├── main.py
└── project # top package directory
    ├── __init__.py # this file is required even if it is empty
    ├── parser
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── parser.py
    └── tests
        └── test_parser.py
```

Also, the `project/project/parser/__init__.py` could contain the following:

```
from .parser import Parser
```

So that your `main.py` file could import the `Parser` class like this:

```
from project.parser import Parser
```

instead of the more tedious:

```
from project.parser.parser import Parser
```

Your `test_parser.py` file, however, will still have to import the `Parser` class like this:

```
from ..parser.parser import Parser
```

because the classes exposed in an `__init__.py` file are not available to relative imports.

Finally, if you are starting a new independent project, you should do it in Python 3 (that's a PEP recommendation), where all the above rules apply, except the `from __future__` imports which are unnecessary.

Sources: https://axialcorps.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/5-simple-rules-for-building-great-python-packages/

Comment: I get the following error if I try `import ..parse.parse` Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import